# ¿Cómo compruebo si hace más de 5 años entre la fecha actual y un valor de una tabla de tipo DATE?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Esta es mi tabla de la cual quiero coger el valoe de host_since y compararlo con la fecha actual para ver si hace más de 5 años entre estas fechas:

```
CREATE TABLE Host(
    ID_host serial,
    host_url VARCHAR (255),
    listing_url VARCHAR (255),
    host_name VARCHAR (255),
    host_since DATE,
    host_about TEXT,
    host_response_time VARCHAR (255),
    host_response_rate VARCHAR (255),
    host_is_superhost VARCHAR (255),
    host_picture_url VARCHAR (255),
    host_listings_count VARCHAR (255),
    host_identity_verified VARCHAR (255),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID_host)
);´´´
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: ¿Que motor de base de datos estas usando?

Answer (score 0):

Hola no se si te entendí bien pero puedes hacer esto esto te trairia los que tienen 5 o mas años

Restarle 5 años a la fecha actual

Para Sql Server

> DATEADD(year, -5, getdate())

```
select * from Host where host_since <= DATEADD(year, -5, getdate())
```

Para Mysql

> DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -5 year)

```
select * from Host where host_since <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -5 year)
```

Para Postgress

> CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '-5 year';

```
  select * from Host where host_since <= CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '-5 year'
```

**Si quieres solo los que tengan 5 años exactos usa**

```
select * from Host where DATE_PART('year', AGE(CURRENT_DATE, host_since)) = 5
```

Comment: el getdate() no existe...

Comment: Esa instrucción es para Sql Server, no se que motor de bd estes usando

Comment: @GASNOBLE sería mucho mas simple si en tu pregunta indicas que motor de bases de datos usas

Comment: utilizo pgAdmin

Answer (score 0):

para obtener la fecha actual se hace uso del campo sysdate from dual desde oracle
database.

```
SELECT host_since , SYSDATE, trunc(((ABS(host_since -SYSDATE)/30)/12),0) AS DIFERENCIA 
FROM Host, DUAL;
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Y que pasa si el OP no usa Oracle?, es mejor pedirle aclare el motor antes de responder o la sintaxis propuesta no le servirá

Comment: uso el motor pgAdmin